# display all sub-level lists inline with css

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float, inline

if i have a list like this one:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    item name
    <ul>
      <li>
        item name
      </li>
      <li>
        item name
        <ul>
          <li>
            item name
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And for example i want each "li" to display inline like its all one sentence... I need this for breadcrumbs...

I tried this:

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

But this wont work because the "ul" or "li" doesn't have a defined width so it goes under.

Any help is welcome,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

`ul{display:inline;}
ul li{display:inline;}
ul li ul li{display:inline;}`

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/QWshN/

Answer (score 0):

Just having text inside of the `<li>` elements is making the text behave like a block-level element itself (effectively wrapping each set of text in a `<p>` tag). If you wrap the text in a `<span>`, for example, and make the span `inline` as well, [you will get the desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/KyZWh/)

Also, use `ul, li, span` as the selector instead of `ul li`

---

Edit:

In fact, if you just change your original CSS to:

```
ul, li {display: inline}
```

it will work perfectly.

Comment: @Karington It works. `display: inline-block` does not work below IE8 (only on naturally `inline` elements).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul ul li` as the selector if you only want the nested ULs to be styled. You also probably don't need `float: left`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sexier:

```
ul, li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jzVcE/

Comment: Your comment up top. Sorry, new to this fancy site

Answer (score 0):

You only want the outer `ul` to be a block level element, so to make all other elements inline elements, you can use:

```
/*  both the inner ul's and the li's */
ul ul,
li
{
  display:inline;
}
```

or, if you want to float them instead:

```
ul
{
  overflow: hidden;    /* make sure the uls wraps around their contents, mainly for outer ´ul´ */
}
ul ul,
li
{
  float: left;
}
```